# Equivalence of definitions for random variable expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have encountered two definitions of expectedvalue of random variable

> **Def. 1**. Let $\xi \geq 0$ be random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. The value$$\mathbb{E}\xi = \sup_{s\in \mathcal{S}: s\leq \xi}{\mathbb{E}s}<\infty,$$
> where $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of simple random variables, is called expected value of $\xi$.

> **Def. 2.**  Let $\xi \geq 0$ be random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and $\{\xi_n \geq 0\}$ be the increasing sequence such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\xi_n(\omega)=\xi(\omega)$ for every $\omega\in \Omega$. The value
> $$\mathbb{E}\xi=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\xi_n <\infty$$
> is called expected value of $\xi$.

In notes I was reading it was proven that **Def. 2** is independent of sequence $\xi_n$, however I didn't get why these two definitions are equivalent, so I need some help with that.

Comment: Have you encountered the monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: @JoseAvilez Yes, is it helpful? It is placed right after definitions

Comment: it's *precisely* the reason why these two definitions are equivalent